# Compiling regular expression: success error occurred

Tags: c, regex

I have this simple code:

```c
regex_t regex;
int re;
if ((re = regcomp(&regex, "^add:([a-zA-Z]{3,},{1}){2}(06)[0-9]{8},{1}([0-9]{10}),{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+@[a-zA-Z]+\\.[a-ZA-Z]+$", REG_EXTENDED))){
    printf("Result: %d ->", re);
    perror("Cannot compile because of");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if ((re = regcomp(&regex, "^remove:[a-zA-Z]{3,}$", REG_EXTENDED))){
    printf("Result: %d ->", re);
    perror("Cannot compile because of");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

When I run the program the output is:

`Result: 11 -> Cannot compile because of: Success`

It enters in the first if statement. But if I write only the first piece of code (so the first if and the declaration of variables) in another file, it works.

I don't understand what's wrong in my code.

Comment: `regcomp()` doesn't set `errno`. It's return value indicates the error. See the manpage for what they are and a description of `regerror()` for turning them into human readable error messages.

Comment: @Shawn Okay thanks, I'll try

Comment: `{1}` is redundant.